# Extract linked data from one row in one table to multiple rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, associations

I am creating a game and have come across the need to select the name from a table (Table1) based on the ID value listed in a single row.

Example of the row

```
RowID Unit1 Unit2 Unit3 Unit4
```

And say that row 1 is populated with data for units as

```
wfmatch

RowID Unit1 Unit2 Unit3 Unit4
----- ----- ----- ----- -----
1     1     2     3     4
```

Then in my second table (`Table2`) I have the actual names

```
wfunits

UnitID Name
------ ----------
1      Firstitem
2      Seconditem
3      Thirditem
4      Fourthitem
```

In one query or as close as possible I would like to be able to obtain the names for the ID's listed from the first table giving a result like so:

```
this is the end result as achieved with code at the bottom. (+4 more names)

RowID Unit1     Unit2      Unit3     Unit4
----- --------- ---------- --------- ----------
1     Firstitem Seconditem Thirditem Fourthitem
```

I have had a go with JOIN statements but I have so far been lacking in the knowledge on how to use them properly and I feel this is probably the way to get the result, I just can't figure it out.

Edit:
Attempted Code

```
SELECT * FROM wfmatch AS t1 INNER JOIN wfunits AS t2 ON t1.crunit1 = t2.id WHERE t1.mid = 1
```

result: negative, only one name provided.

Working end result:

```
SELECT
m.mid, u1.name AS Unit1, u2.name AS Unit2, u3.name AS Unit3, u4.name AS Unit4,
u5.name AS Unit5, u6.name AS Unit6, u7.name AS Unit7, u8.name AS Unit8
FROM wfmatch AS m  
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u1 ON m.crunit1=u1.id  
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u2 ON m.crunit2=u2.id 
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u3 ON m.crunit3=u3.id 
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u4 ON m.crunit4 =u4.id 
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u5 ON m.counit1=u5.id 
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u6 ON m.counit2=u6.id 
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u7 ON m.counit3=u7.id  
INNER JOIN wfunits AS u8 ON m.counit4 =u8.id 
WHERE mid=1
```

Comment: thanks @Andriy M, couldn't figure out the formatting thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need four joins, one per column, like this:

```sql
SELECT
  m.RefID,
  u1.Name AS Unit1,
  u2.Name AS Unit2,
  u3.Name AS Unit3,
  u4.Name AS Unit4
FROM Table1 AS m
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS u1 ON m.Unit1 = u1.UnitID
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS u2 ON m.Unit2 = u2.UnitID
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS u3 ON m.Unit3 = u3.UnitID
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS u4 ON m.Unit4 = u4.UnitID
```

There's also an alternative, although I'm not sure if it would be better:

```sql
SELECT
  m.RefID,
  MAX(CASE u.UnitID WHEN m.Unit1 THEN u.Name END) AS Unit1,
  MAX(CASE u.UnitID WHEN m.Unit2 THEN u.Name END) AS Unit2,
  MAX(CASE u.UnitID WHEN m.Unit3 THEN u.Name END) AS Unit3,
  MAX(CASE u.UnitID WHEN m.Unit4 THEN u.Name END) AS Unit4
FROM Table1 AS m
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS u ON u.UnitID IN (m.Unit1, m.Unit2, m.Unit3, m.Unit4)
GROUP BY m.RefID
```

Comment: I will test this when I get home and post the results

Comment: Top stuff it works. Couldn't wait to get home so mobile queried it

Comment: I am liking the second version better though as it doesnt matter about null fields then

Comment: @Adsy2010: Ah, but in that case you could modify the first one to become NULL-friendly too. Just use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: @Adsy2010: You can read more on joins in MySQL on [this MySQL manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html "JOIN Syntax (MySQL)"), if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.rowid = ?
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM wfmatch AS t1 INNER JOIN wfunits AS t2 ON t1.crunit1 = t2.id WHERE t1.mid = 1 is the code I tried and yes it shows 1 name but not 4. I also have: t1.crunit2 t1.crunit3 t1.crunit4 to get names for + another set of 4 but once I know how to get 4 or close to i can figure the rest out

Comment: It appears your answer was along the right lines, thanks for your contribution.