# postgres join queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 postgresql tables as follows

employees

```
emp_name | emp_id | user_name | psw | etc
```

work

```
Work_id |work_type| Project_manger_id(employee) | Architect_id (emp) | tech_lead_id | dept_id
```

dept

```
dept_id | dept_name
```

now what I want is a table like this

```
work_type | project_manager (name)  | architect (name) | tech_lead (name ) | dept (name )
```

Simply, what I want is to get the work table but replacing id's with names

Comment: Welcome to SO -- what have you tried?

Comment: what I'm stuck on is , I don't know exactly how to merge work table with employee , since I hv to get employee names matching , project_manager_id with emp_id , architect_id with emp_id , tech_lead_id with emp_id , how can I do this , so far what I did was some thing like this 
SELECT e1.emp_name, e2.emp_name , e3.emp_name , w.work_id 
FROM employees e1, employees e2, employees e3,work w
Where
e1.emp_id_id = w.project_manager_id
AND
e2.emp_id = w.architect_id
AND
e3.emp_id = w.tech_lead_id ;

Comment: in this way I can get it done , but only problem is is there is no value for a employee , then whole tuple is ignored by this , :(

Comment: Very similar to a [recent MySQL question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774469/extract-linked-data-from-one-row-in-one-table-to-multiple-rows-in-another-table "Extract linked data from one row in one table to multiple rows in another table") (with suggestions equally applicable to PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Select WT.Work_Type,PM.emp_name As ProjectManager,AR.emp_name AS Arhitect,TL.emp_name As  TechLead,Dept.Dept_name As Department From
Work 
INNER JOIN employees AS PM ON (Wt.Project_manger_id=PM.emp_id)
INNER JOIN employees AS AR ON (Wt.Architect_id=AR.emp_id)
INNER JOIN employees AS TL ON (Wt.tech_lead_id=TL.emp_id)
INNER JOIN Dept As Dept ON (Wt.dept_id=Dept.dept_id)
```